# VirtualPathProvider issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, virtualpathprovider

Implemented a virtual path provider to dynamically load some files from a shared project in a new web application. Everything works fine in dev/deployed and local IIS. When deploying to production we are encountering  "Failed to start monitoring file changes" error when trying to find a 'virtual file'. GetCacheDependency is overridden in our VirtualPathProvider but when I remote debug the function is never hit. Any Ideas?

EDIT:

```
  public override System.Web.Caching.CacheDependency GetCacheDependency(string virtualPath, System.Collections.IEnumerable virtualPathDependencies, DateTime utcStart)
    {
        if (CheckVirtual(virtualPath))
        {

            string realName = CustomVirtualPathProvider.CleansePath(virtualPath);

            return new System.Web.Caching.CacheDependency(baseDirectory + realName);

        }

        return Previous.GetCacheDependency(virtualPath, virtualPathDependencies, utcStart);
    }
```

I register the VPP in the global asax. It only fails in production which leads me to believe that its a iis settings issue.

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[image]

Comment: I think you'll need to post some of the contents of your method.

Comment: My VirtualPathProvider seems to work the same way, the only difference I can see is that I use `return new System.Web.Caching.CacheDependency(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/" + theDependencyFileName), utcStart);`. You could try that, even though I have no idea why it should make a difference, if your baseDirectory is correct... Also, instead of `Previous.GetCacheDependency` I use `base.GetCacheDependency`. That might be why it throws on a web service.

Comment: I've tried Previous and Base without any difference still seeing the same problem. I'll give your other suggestion a try and let you know